# How does Catholic Church reconcile the time of and the manner in which Jesus' resurrection was disclosed to Apostles?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, gospels, apostles, resurrection-of-jesus

We read in Mk 16:1-8, the the Angel's  instruction to the  women who visited the tomb of Jesus on the day of his Resurrection, and its  outcome:

> When the sabbath was over, Mary Magdalene, and Mary the mother of James, and Salome bought spices, so that they might go and anoint him...... As they entered the tomb, they saw a young man, dressed in a white robe, sitting on the right side; and they were alarmed.  But he said to them  .... . go, tell his disciples and Peter that he is going ahead of you to Galilee; there you will see him, just as he told you. So they went out and fled from the tomb, for terror and amazement had seized them; and they said nothing to anyone, for they were afraid.

We read a somewhat different account of what the women did on returning from the tomb, in Lk 24:9-10:

> Then they remembered his words, and returning from the tomb, they told all this to the eleven and to all the rest.   Now it was Mary Magdalene, Joanna, Mary the mother of James, and the other women with them who told this to the apostles.

There is an apparent contradiction in the time of and the manner in which the news of Jesus' resurrection was disclosed to the Apostles, going by the account given by Mark vis-a-vis that given by Luke. My question therefore, is: **How does the Catholic Church reconcile the apparent contradiction  in the time of and the manner in which the news of Jesus' resurrection was disclosed to the Apostles?**

Comment: I don't see the contradiction.

Comment: Please focus on Mk 16:8 :".. they said nothing to anyone, for they were afraid " and  Lk 24: 9 :"..returning from the tomb, they told all this to the eleven and to all the rest." . You will find the difference.

Comment: I suggest Mark leaves room for the meaning to be "they said nothing to anyone (else)" or "nothing to anyone (on the way to tell the disciples).  Otherwise they disobey the command of verse 7 and contradict the other account.

Comment: Interestingly, Mk 16: 8 of AKJV reads : "And they went out quickly, and fled from the sepulchre; for they trembled and were amazed: neither said they any thing to any man; for they were afraid. " . They may have told the Blessed Mother and other ladies who in turn would have informed the Apostles.

Comment: But Luke tells us, "Now it was Mary Magdalene and Joanna and Mary the mother of James and the other women with them who told these things to the apostles".  "Man" in Mark is any person, not a male specifically.  Matthew 28:8-10 records Jesus appearing to them on the way and telling them not to be afraid.  When you collate all of the accounts it makes sense.